# Core Data relationship error

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I want to save a Goal and an Actor. The two entities are related with an Responsibility-relationship:

```
Goal *addgoal = (Goal*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Goal" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    addgoal.goalNaam = nameTextField.text;
    addgoal.goalId = idField.text;
    addgoal.goalBeschrijving = beschrijvingField.text;

    Actor *addactor = (Actor*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Actor" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    addactor.actorNaam = responsibleField.text;

    [addgoal addResponsibilityObject:addactor];
```

the line above ([addgoal addResponsibility:addactor]) is causing the error, what is wrong ?

in Goal.h:

```
@interface Goal (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addResponsibilityObject:(Actor *)value;
@end
```

Error:

2012-08-02 20:57:11.838 Choose3[7434:fb03] -[__NSCFSet entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8877810
2012-08-02 20:57:11.840 Choose3[7434:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8877810'

Comment: Somewhere you're trying to call a method named `entity` but you're calling it on the wrong type of object.

Comment: There's no method 'entity'. Is it necessary to implement '- (void)addResponsibilityObject:(Actor *)value;' ?

Comment: You'll need to give us the implementation of `- (void)addResponsibilityObject:(Actor *)value;`

Comment: Actually, there is a method `entity`; it exists for a number of different classes related to Core Data.  The error message is claiming that `entity` is being called on a NSSet, which is not one of the classes that has it.  Is "Responsibility" a too-many relationship...it's almost as if Core Data is confused about that?

Comment: @JeffWolski, I didn't implement this method, is this necessary ? Right now I tried '[[addgoal mutableSetValueForKey:@"responsibility"] addObject:addactor];        ' instead and still got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Core Data is confused about the nature of the Responsibility relationship.  I suggest creating `NSManagedObject` subclasses that match the current state of your data model.

One way to create this error would be to change a to-many relationship into a to-one relationship without re-generating the entity class files.

Comment: I've regenerated my class files, still getting this error (all relationships are to many- relationships in my model.

The weird thing is:

 `NSString *naamActor = [goal valueForKeyPath:@"responsibility.actorNaam"];
     NSLog(@"Naam actor will appear: %@", naamActor);
    responsibleField.text = [goal valueForKeyPath:@"responsibility.actorNaam"];`
The NSLog works (he gives me the naamActor)
but the naamActor can't be displayed in the textfield..

Answer (score 6):

I just encountered the same problem. The solution here was, that I forgot to check the "To-Many" option in the relationship options within the model inspector.